# OkHttp: Lack of possibility to change charset for post request

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I need to post form data with some rare charset, and...

Instead of addFormDataPart(name, value@rareCharset), I figued out from sources that it can be
apply { addPart(MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(name, null, value@RareCharset.toRequestBody("text/plain; charset=rareCharset".toMediaType()))) }.
BUT there is nothig I can use instead of addFormDataPart(name, filename@RareCharset, data).
There is deeply hardcoded "utf-8" as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy the MultipartBody class into your project. It’s self-contained and you can do whatever you like with exotic charsets.